# Implementation load, update, remove functions in react js using DataGrid and axios

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, datagrid

Can anyone help me to understand what I do wrong? I want to get data from MySQL database and display it in DataGrid. The code from this file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DataGrid, { Column, Editing, Paging } from 'devextreme-react/data-grid'
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source'
import axios from 'axios'

//data = [{"idInstitute" : 34, "nameInstitute" : "hkjsdhjk"}]

export default class Institute extends Component {
  

  render () {
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: 'auto', width: '60%', marginTop: '100px' }}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '30px' }}>Институты</h1>
        <DataGrid
          id='gridContainer'
          dataSource= { new DataSource(
            {
              key: 'idInstitute',
              loadMode: 'processed',
              load : function (loadOptions) {
                  return axios.get('http://localhost:3002/institute')
                              .then(res => { return JSON.stringify(res.data); })
                              .catch( e => { throw e;} );
              }
              /*update : function() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:3002/institute').then(res => { JSON.stringify(res.data)});
                return this.data;
              }*/
              
            } )}
          keyExpr="idInstitute"
          //allowColumnReordering
          showBorders
          //onEditingStart={this.onEditingStart}
          onInitNewRow={this.onInitNewRow}
          //onRowInserting={this.onRowInserting}
          //onRowInserted={this.onRowInserted}
          //onRowUpdating={this.onRowUpdating}
          //onRowUpdated={this.onRowUpdated}
          //onRowRemoving={this.onRowRemoving}
          //onRowRemoved={this.onRowRemoved}
          remoteOperations={true}
        >

          <Paging enabled />
          <Editing
                mode='row'
                allowUpdating
                allowDeleting
                allowAdding
                useIcons
              />

          <Column dataField='idInstitute' caption='ID' width={50} visible={false} />
          <Column dataField='nameInstitute' caption='Название института' />

        </DataGrid>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If I write "dataSource = [{"idInstitute"  : 1, "nameInstitute" : "fdsfsdq"}, ...]" it works properly. But I want to get information from my back-end which is used MySQL as database. In the browsers, this page display JSON information from my database and in the terminal I also get this successfully. The code of test.js (for the terminal):

```js
const axios = require('axios')

let result = []
axios.get('http://localhost:3002/institute').then(res => {
    console.log( JSON.stringify( res.data ) )
})
//console.log(result)
```

But in the application I have an network error or infinity loading (if remove 'return' before 'axios.get()').

[network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIt9o.png)

[infinity loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nidm.png)

Full of this project you can see on my GitHub repositories.

Front-end: https://github.com/Geloger37/pub-activity-front

Back-end: https://github.com/Geloger37/pub-activity-back

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to save your api data(axios response) into react state then render it using Datagrid

```
export default class Institute extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://yoururl.com')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.data.map(e=>{return <li>{e.objectProperty}</li>}) //you need to use Datagrid instead of li tag
    )
  }
}
```